# YOCTO how to create a basic ubuntu 16.04 linux

Tags: ubuntu, yocto, bitbake

What if I am obbliged to use Yocto, but I don't need a custom o.s. Instead I prefer a common ubuntu 16.04. Is there a way to create it using the yocto enviroment?

Comment: If you want a common ubuntu distribution, just take it. Use Yocto if you want to make your own embedded Linux distribution, that is the whole purpose of the Yocto project.

Comment: Sure, but what if the board supplier doesn't provide a custom version of ubuntu but just provide the yocto enviroment with the  board supplier-layer?

Comment: Well, if you're getting an OE (Yocto)-based SDK, then you'll either have to you it OE / Yocto, or you'll have to add the BSP to something else... You can't build Ubuntu using OE. OE / Yocto is all about creating your own distro.

Comment: Then I would try to build the yocto environment with bitbake. I think that trying to build something ubuntu like with the sources you have is much more effort than building your own distribution. Getting started with yocto is surely some effort, but I would say it is the way to go here.

Comment: Ok I got it. What about customize ubuntu for my board vs  build custom os with yocto ?
Since we are in a development phase, I would like to avoid a custom o.s at this moment.

Comment: I believe builds of Ubuntu for embedded systems do exist, but I strongly advice you to not go this way. For customizing your OS using Yocto there is an extensive community, documentation, and companies which provide BSP's and/or support on  your way. Going rogue with unusual solution will give you zero to none support, you will be basically on your own. Consider time constraints of project and your opinion on crunch, deadlines are there for sure. Also, Yocto will be a new usable set of knowledge for you. Learning curve is harsh, but you won't regret investing your time in it.

Comment: Well, could you kindly tell me some example of difficulties that i will face during the customization? basically, why is not suggested?
Ok yocto is the "easy" way, but what about advantage for the development phase? With YOCYO I wont be able to install new things quickly right?

Answer (score 6):

The answer is "yes", you can use Yocto to create a customized Ubuntu, but it needs some patches to a stock Yocto to make it work.

See https://www.nxp.com/support/developer-resources/run-time-software/linux-software-and-development-tools/bsp-for-s32v-and-bluebox-technology:BSP-S32V

The Yocto provided there can build either a "classic" Yocto image or a Ubuntu based image containing also Yocto built elements. The Ubuntu build works cross architecture.

Rationale being that while you can't easily build a full Ubuntu from source, you can use Yocto as deterministic environment to put a customized Ubuntu together in a repeatable way.

Answer (score -2):

In short: NO.

Its just a different thing entirely. You can either use some ubuntu-based distribution and customize it, OR build a custom distribution. There's nothing bad with basing your thing ob ubuntu (or debian, or whatever), but the there's just no Yocto/OpenEmbedded involved.

Think a bit about like, maybe, Toyota versus BMW. Both will serve their purpose. But if you go to the Toyota manufacturing plant and ask them to build a BMW for you, they won't do it. Not even if you pay enough, but because they're just not equipped for it, they don't have the blueprints, etc - and the same vice-versa. Its not a question of "don't want to do". Its a case of "cannot, because just completely different thing"